# VSCode で JavaFX をインポートできない

Tags: java, vscode, javafx

VSCode で JavaFX を import しようとすると 'The import javafx cant be resolved' と表示されて使うことができません。JavaFX に必要な 'jaavafx-sdk-1.0.2' というフォルダに入っている jar ファイルは全てライブラリに追加したのですがだめでした。

また、JavaFX は最新の JDK では対応していないらしいので adoptopenjdk8 を使おうと思ったのですが、VSCode の settings.json の java.home に adoptopenjdk8 のディレクトリを書き込んだら 'The java.home variable defined in visual studio code settings does not point to a jdk' と表示されて使うことができませんでした。

JavaFX を VSCode でインポートできるようにするにはどうすればいいでしょうか。
ご教示お願いします。

Comment: この辺の記事のどれかが参考になるかも。[JavaFX15を導入してVSCodeでGUI開発を行う](https://qiita.com/kazushi47/items/66fbd4a6b3db8e7c2851), [【グッバイEclipse】VSCodeでJavaの開発環境を構築するための設定方法【import保管やデバッグ確認まで出来ちゃう】](https://blogenist.jp/2019/11/06/9687/), [How to resolve 'import javafx cannot be resolved' in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56561102/9014308), [JavaFX-11 with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54349894/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vscodeにjava extension pack が導入されているのであれば、MavenプロジェクトからJavaFXのアーキタイプを選択する方法が手っ取り早くJavaFXを実行する方法であると思います。

次の手順で実行します。

1. コマンドパレット<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>から、`Maven: Create Maven Project` を選択。
2. アーキタイプの選択を促されるが、一番上の`More`をクリック
3. テキストボックスに`openjfx`と入力し、出てきた候補から`javafx-archetype-simple`を選択（もしfamlを使いたかったら`javafx-archetype-faml`を選択してください）
4. バージョンを聞かれるので、一番最新のバージョンを選択。
5. GroupIDとArtifactIDを入力する。デフォルトの名前でも任意に入力しても良いです。
6. フォルダ選択ダイアログが表示されるので、プロジェクトを作成するフォルダを選択します。
7. ターミナルにプロジェクト作成の進捗ログが表示されていきます。途中何度か入力を促されます。とりあえず動作させることが目的であれば全て<kbd>Enter</kbd>入力で良いと思います。
8. ターミナルに`BUILD SUCCESS`と表示されればプロジェクト作成完了です。同時に新しいウィンドウでプロジェクトを開くかどうかのダイアログが表示されます。新しくウィンドウを開いた方が作業しやすいので`Open`を選択しましょう。
9. この方法で作成したプロジェクトには、"Hello JavaFX"を表示する簡単なフレームを表示するクラス`App.java`が予め実装されています。`App.java`を開き、<kbd>F5</kbd>キーやメニューで実行またはデバッグを選択し、無事ウィンドウが表示されればひとまず完了です。

JDKは8が推奨だと思いますが、11でも動作しました(Pleiades All in oneに付属のAdopt openjdkです)

あとはこのプロジェクトをベースに目的のアプリケーションを作っていきましょう。